Why is networking not working on “Ubuntu22.04.img” VM under KVM Ubuntu 22.04?
I  am trying about 5 hours now and cannot get it work. I want that my VM can get access to the Internet.
Host Ubuntu 22.04 with kvm/virt-manager installed
followed different how to's (mostly the same, other IP's thats all) configured bridge with netplan like follow:
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false

  # Add configuration for bridge interface
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eno1]
      addresses: [192.168.178.152/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.178.1
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
        search: []
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
  version: 2

$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:0e:3c:99:31:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp16s0
3: wlo1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:dd:24:ce:3f:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3
4: br-c704ca5d8c45: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:fb:ba:75:53 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.1/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global br-c704ca5d8c45
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:fbff:feba:7553/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c7:52:91:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
26: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6a:09:6f:ae:94:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.152/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6809:6fff:feae:9402/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
34: vnet7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:41:8c:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe41:8c35/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


I set up Ubuntu22.04.img with virt-manager and NIC with:
<interface type="bridge">
  <mac address="52:54:00:41:8c:35"/>
  <source bridge="br0"/>
  <target dev="vnet7"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x07" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>

I wonder about what is this vnet7? It was automatically created from virt-manager, but why and for what?
<interface type="bridge">
  <mac address="52:54:00:41:8c:35"/>
  <source bridge="br0"/>
  <target dev="vnet7"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x07" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>

DHCP is not working and I tried with static IP and many different IP's inside the VM, no idea what to do now.
At one point (I got static .153) I could ping the .152 (bridge) but cannot get further.
All virtual networks are deleted.
